# c - double free or corruption where there arent frees

Tags: c, free, corruption

Well, i have done the fallowing code ( basically want i want to do is: i have a list where i have some obstacles, if x=-1, the obstacles are in an entire floor,  else, they are only at one place, so i want to make each time i go through the code, that the obstacles are in that position):

```
void restartmatrix(parking * parklot, block * obstacles, int time) {
    int x, y, z;
    block * tempblock;
    for (z = 0; z < parklot->depth; z++) {
        for (x = 0; x < parklot->width; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < parklot->height; y++) {
                (parklot - > floors[x][y][z]).percorrido = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    /*tempblock = obstacles;
    while(tempblock != NULL){
        if(tempblock->start = time){
            if(tempblock->x != -1){
                for(x=0; x < parklot->width; x++){
                    for(y = 0; y < parklot->height; y++){
                        (parklot->floors[x][y][tempblock->z]).percorrido = 1;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                (parklot->floors[tempblock->x][tempblock->y][tempblock->z]).percorrido = 1;
            }
        }else if(tempblock->end == time && tempblock->end != 0){
            if(tempblock->x != -1){
                for(x=0; x < parklot->width; x++){
                    for(y = 0; y < parklot->height; y++){
                        (parklot->floors[x][y][tempblock->z]).percorrido = -1;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                (parklot->floors[tempblock->x][tempblock->y][tempblock->z]).percorrido = -1;
            }
        }
    tempblock = tempblock->next;
    }*/
}
```

Has you can see some part of the code is commented....well, the problem is if uncomment it, the program gives me a double free or corruption error (fasttop) but i can't seem to find why, since i haven't done any free...

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

The code where i allocate the list of obstacles is here, if it can help:

```
block * read_blocking_list(char * file){
FILE * fp;
char leitura[256];  
char temporary;
block * head = NULL;
block * temp;
block * aux;
int start, end, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, size;

fp = fopen(file, "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro de leitura\n");
    exit(0);
}
while(fgets(leitura, 255, fp) != NULL){
    temp = malloc(sizeof(block));
    size = sscanf(leitura, "%c %d %d %d %d %d", &temporary, &start, &end, &x, &y, &z);
    temp->start = start;
    temp->end = end;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(size < 5){
        temp->x = -1;
        temp->z = x;
    }else{
        temp->x = x;
        temp->y = y;
        temp->z = z;
    }
    if(head == NULL){
        head = temp;
    }else{
        aux = head;
        while(aux->next != NULL){
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        aux->next = temp;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
return head;
}
```

Comment: Tried running your program in `valgrind` to find memory corruption errors more easily?

Comment: running it through valgrind gives me segmentation fault too...

Comment: chqrlie the code isn't like that....suppose it was a moderator...

Comment: It is safer to comment code with `#if 0 / #endif`.  Using multiline comments fails if the block contains comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful of `=` versus `==`:

```
if(tempblock->start = time){
```

should be

```
if(tempblock->start == time){
```

---

Also, this block of code:

```
if(tempblock->x != -1){
    for(x=0; x < parklot->width; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < parklot->height; y++){
            (parklot->floors[x][y][tempblock->z]).percorrido = 1;    
        }
    }
}else{
    (parklot->floors[tempblock->x][tempblock->y[tempblock>z]).percorrido = 1;
}
```

Is like saying:

```
if(tempblock->x != -1){
    /* Do some stuff here while tempblock->x is NOT -1. */
}else{
    /* So in this block, tempblock->x IS EQUAL TO -1. */
    (parklot->floors[tempblock->x][tempblock->y][tempblock->z]).percorrido = 1;
}
```

So, trying to clearly illustrate where that leaves us, we have:

```
if(tempblock->x != -1){
    /* Do some stuff here while tempblock->x is NOT -1. */
}else{
    /* So in this block, tempblock->x IS EQUAL TO -1. */
    (parklot->floors[-1][tempblock->y][tempblock->z]).percorrido = 1;
}
```

Notice the `parklot->floors[-1]`.  You are definitely out of bounds.

Comment: `if(tempblock->start = time){` would have been diagnosed by the compiler if invoked with the proper warnings enabled: `gcc -Wall -W -Werror`

Comment: @chqrlie you are probably right but i know MANY people who ignore warnings.

Comment: Yes, the problem was what you said, the "if(tempblock->start = time){" and the -1, not even noticed...but i didn't have any warning....

Comment: @RedX: yes, it is the sad truth.  It seems to be human nature to ignore warnings, no matter what is at stake.  The surgeon general is not successful either...  At least `-Werror` prevents compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You test if `tempblock-x != -1` and use `tempblock->x` in the `else` block this way:

```
(parklot->floors[tempblock->x][tempblock->y][tempblock->z]).percorrido = 1;
```

Thus you are most likely indexing out of bounds.  Check your logic.

Comment: If you check better the logic, i only do that if tempblock->x != -1 :D, see the if and the else

Comment: I'm afraid you are mistaken: in the `else` branch, `tempblock->x` **is** equal to `-1`, therefore you dereference `parklot->floors[-1]`, invoking undefined behavior.  writing to this location probably causes corruption of the heap structures, resulting in a later *double free or corruption error* as diagnosed by the heap consistency checks. DuaneMcCully gave a much more detailed explanation for this problem (and pointed another silly mistake).